# Product Thumbnail Overlapping the Main Image in Product Page

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

Any idea how to fix product thumbnail that is overlapping on my product image? i want to put it below product image and not inside the product image.

[that is how the product page look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMnko.jpg)

this the product template liquid. i have edit a little as the original product page, the product is arranged vertically in very large image

```css
<!-- /templates/product.liquid -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="ProductSection" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="product-template" data-image-zoom-type="{{ section.settings.zoom_enable }}" data-enable-history-state="true">
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <meta itemprop="url" content="{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}">

    {% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}

    <div class="grid product-single">
      <div class="grid__item large--seven-twelfths medium--seven-twelfths text-center">

       <div class="product-single__photos small--hide">
{% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}

{% comment %}
  Get all images for gallery, but only show one at a time
{% endcomment %}
<div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
  <img class="product-single__photo" id="ProductPhotoImg" src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ featured_image.id }}">
  {% for image in product.images %}
    {% unless image contains featured_image %}
      <img class="product-single__photo" src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" style="display: none;" />
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% comment %}
  Display thumbnails
{% endcomment %}
<ul class="product-single__thumbnails grid-uniform" id="ProductThumbs">
  {% for image in product.images %}
      <li class="grid__item medium--one-quarter large--one-fifth product-single__photo-wrapper">
        <a data-image-id="{{ image.id }}" {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}
           href="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" class="product-single__thumbnail">
          <img class="product-single__thumb" src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
        </a>
      </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

</div>
<div class="mobile product-single__photos medium--hide large--hide">
{% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}

{% comment %}
  Display current variant image, or default first
{% endcomment %}
<div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
  <img class="mobile product-single__photo" id="ProductPhotoImg" src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ featured_image.id }}">
</div>

{% comment %}
  Display rest of product images, not repeating the featured one
{% endcomment %}
{% for image in product.images %}
  {% unless image contains featured_image %}
    <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
      <img class="mobile product-single__photo" src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
    </div>
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid__item product-single__meta--wrapper medium--five-twelfths large--five-twelfths">
        <div class="product-single__meta">
          {% if section.settings.product_vendor_enable %}
            <h2 class="product-single__vendor" itemprop="brand">{{ product.vendor }}</h2>
          {% endif %}

          <h1 class="product-single__title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</h1>

          <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            {% comment %}
              Optionally show the 'compare at' or original price of the product.
            {% endcomment %}

            {% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}
              <span id="PriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.general.regular_price' | t }}</span>
              <span class="product-single__price--wrapper">
                <span id="ComparePrice" class="product-single__price--compare-at">
                  {% if current_variant.compare_at_price > current_variant.price %}
                    {{ current_variant.compare_at_price | money }}
                  {% endif %}
                </span>
              </span>
              <span id="ComparePriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.general.sale_price' | t }}</span>
            {% else %}
              <span id="PriceA11y" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.general.regular_price' | t }}</span>
            {% endif %}

            <span id="ProductPrice"
              class="product-single__price{% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %} on-sale{% endif %}"
              itemprop="price"
              content="{{ current_variant.price | divided_by: 100.00 }}">
              {{ current_variant.price | money }}
            </span>

{% if product.compare_at_price_max > product.price %}You saved 
            {{ product.compare_at_price_max | minus: product.price | times: 100.0 | divided_by: product.compare_at_price_max | money_without_currency | times: 100 | remove: '.0'}}%{% endif %}

            <hr class="hr--small">

            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{{ shop.currency }}">
            <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/{% if product.available %}InStock{% else %}OutOfStock{% endif %}">

            <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-single__form" id="AddToCartForm">
              {% unless product.options.size == 1 and product.variants[0].title == 'Default Title' %}
                {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
                  <div class="radio-wrapper js product-form__item">
                    <label class="single-option-radio__label{% if option.name == 'Default' or option.name == 'Title' %} hidden-label{% endif %}"
                      for="ProductSelect-option-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                      {{ option.name }}
                    </label>
                    <fieldset class="single-option-radio"
                      name="{{ option.name }}"
                      id="ProductSelect-option-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                      {% assign option_index = forloop.index %}
                      {% for value in option.values %}
                        {% assign variant_label_state = true %}
                        {% if product.options.size == 1 %}
                          {% unless product.variants[forloop.index0].available  %}
                            {% assign variant_label_state = false %}
                          {% endunless %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <input type="radio"
                          {% if option.selected_value == value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
                          {% unless variant_label_state %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}
                          value="{{ value | escape }}"
                          data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
                          name="{{ option.name }}"
                          class="single-option-selector__radio{% unless variant_label_state %} disabled{% endunless %}"
                          id="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name }}-{{ value | escape }}">
                        <label for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name }}-{{ value | escape }}"{% unless variant_label_state %} class="disabled"{% endunless %}>{{ value | escape }}</label>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              {% endunless %}

              <select name="id" id="ProductSelect" class="product-single__variants no-js">
                {% for variant in product.variants %}
                  {% if variant.available %}
                    <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
                      selected="selected" {% endif %}
                      data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}"
                      value="{{ variant.id }}">
                      {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
                    </option>
                  {% else %}
                    <option disabled="disabled">
                      {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                    </option>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </select>


              <div class="product-single__quantity">
                <label for="Quantity" class="product-single__quantity-label js-quantity-selector">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
                <input type="number" hidden="hidden" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="js-quantity-selector">
              </div>


              <div class="product-single__add-to-cart">
                <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn"{% unless product.available %} disabled="disabled"{% endunless %}>
                  <span id="AddToCartText">
                    {% if product.available %}
                      {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                    {% else %}
                      {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                    {% endif %}
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>

          </div>

          <div class="product-single__description rte" itemprop="description">
            {{ product.description }}
          </div>

          {% if section.settings.social_sharing_products %}
            {% include 'social-sharing', share_title: product.title, share_permalink: product.url, share_image: product %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% if collection %}
      <hr class="hr--clear">
      <div class="text-center">
        <a href="{{ collection.url }}" class="return-link">&larr; {{ 'products.general.collection_return' | t: collection: collection.title }}</a>
      </div>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
</div>
{% unless product.empty == empty %}
  <script type="application/json" id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}">
    {{ product | json }}
  </script>
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: post your code, what you have tried.

Comment: @hash, i have edit the code above as the previous product page is different. it have vertically large image and hard for user to scroll to see every product